# Given a .txt file, I need to lower case and remove punctuation

Tags: java

I'm working on a smaller part of a larger group project. Within this scope i'm taking in a text file and converting it to a easier to compress text file. To do this i'm lowering all the upper case words as well as replacing punctuation with a blank space(i.e. " " ). I appreciate all comments and recommendation.

```
import java.io.*;
public class Formatter
{

    public static void main (String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        String nonChar = ".,:;!@#$%^&*()_-=+[]\"'<>";
        File f1 = new File("iTest.txt");
        File f2 = new File("oTest.txt");
        BufferedReader in = (new BufferedReader(new FileReader(f1)));
        PrintWriter out = (new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(f2)));

        int ch;
        while ((ch = in.read()) != -1)
        {
            if (Character.isUpperCase(ch))
            {
                ch = Character.toLowerCase(ch);
            }
            else if (in.contains(Character[ch]))//tried character
            {
                ch = ' ';
            }
            out.write(ch);
        }

        in.close();
        out.close();

    }
}
```

Ideally, If it was given

```
Peter Piper picked a peck of pickled peppers;
A peck of pickled peppers Peter Piper picked;
If Peter Piper picked a peck of pickled peppers,
Where's the peck of pickled peppers Peter Piper picked?
```

it would return

```
peter piper picked a peck of pickled peppers
a peck of pickled peppers peter piper picked
if peter piper picked a peck of pickled peppers
where s the peck of pickled peppers peter piper picked
```

Comment: What is the question?

Answer (score 4):

Read line by line as `String` and perform the operation:

```
BufferedReader in = (new BufferedReader(new FileReader(f1)));
String line;
String processedLine="";
while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
    processedLine = line.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9]"," ").toLowerCase().replaceAll("( )+", " ");
    out.write(processedLine);
    out.write(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
}
```

Note: You can use `line.replaceAll("(?U)[^\\p{Alnum}]"," ")` if the text include some unique character(accented characters) such as `é`, etc

Comment: For support for characters like 'é', you can use `"(?U)[^\\p{Alnum}]"` or just `"(?U)[^\\w]"` instead of `"[^a-zA-Z0-9]"`. Also, while it's fine for simple input, for large input you'd want use a `StringBuilder` for string appends.

Answer (score 1):

you could do this in just a few lines

```
String text;
BufferedReader in = (new BufferedReader(new FileReader(f1)));
text = in.readLine();
text = text.replaceAll("[^\\w\\s\\ ]", " ").toLowerCase();
```

this would work if the text is just one line, if it is multiple lines you would just have to loop the above code.